# How can I terminate a connection to particular peerID?

Tags: ios, gamekit, gksession

I'm using `GKSession` in PEERMODE to establish multiple connections with different devices.

```
[I(denoted as Z) have 3 connections with A, B and C.]

   (All with same session ID)
      <-----> A
    Z <-----> B
      <-----> C
```

But I can't figure out how to terminate a particular connection with specific peerID like the following:

```
      <-----> A
    Z <--x--> B    disconnect with B, but A & C remain connected
      <-----> C
```

I've read the reference of `GKSession` Class and do some search on web, but didn't find any useful information, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

`- (void)disconnectPeerFromAllPeers:(NSString *)peerID`

with peerID of B ?
Regards!

Comment: On another SO question whose URL I don't remember anymore, someone wrote that he had to disconnect a pier by sending it a package with a "shouldDisconnect" command and this peer then disconnects itself from the network and kills its session.